# How can I get current time as 09:04:15 instead of 9:4:15 when using Date?

Tags: java, android, date, time, calendar

I am trying to get current time as e.g. 09:04:15. As of now I have been using

```
    long unixTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
    Date time=new java.util.Date((long)unixTime*1000);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(time);
    int hours = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minutes = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int seconds = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);


    currentTime = (hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds);
```

Which gives 9:4:15 instead. What is the best way to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: The keyword here is "**format**", and your question is: *How to format date in Java*. Web search for [that](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+format+date+in+Java) finds you a gazillion answers.

Comment: You are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes. For Android, see the ThreeTenABP project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SimpleDateFormat`, e.g.:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 4):

Keep it simple:
No calendar required, no div by 1000 and then multiply again, just do:

```
Date time = new java.util.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(time));
```

will print

> 13:04:19

adding leading zeros

Answer (score 3):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println("Current time => "+c.getTime());

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
```

Answer (score 3):

## java.time

```
LocalTime.now()
         .toString()
```

> 09:04:15

Much of the java.time functionality built into Java 8 & 9 and later is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the ThreeTen-BackPort project and further adapted to Android in the ThreeTenABP project.

Answer (score 2):

Use simpledateformat method

```
String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use next code:

```
currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(cal.getTime());
```